# Prevent form from submitting does not work in wordpress with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, wpforms

I have a wordpress site (v.6.0.2) and I also have a contact form built with the WPForms plugin. What I am trying to do is to prevent the form from submitting when the name field does not contain two words (Name and Surname) in order to restrict spam messages.

In the `functions.php` I registered my script in the following way:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );

function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_script.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );
}
```

`my_script.js` in the js folder of my theme is:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$("#wpforms-form-2185").submit(function( event ) {
    $("input#wpforms-2185-field_0").each(function() {
        var words = $.trim($(this).val()).split(" ");
        //alert(words.length);
        if(words.length != 2) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong and my form keeps submitting in every way I put names on?

**Edit 1**
My form gets submitted even with a single name word. These are the info messages from the Chrome console:

**Screenshot 1**
[image]

**Screenshot 2**
[image]

and the code from the `formSubmit` from the `wpforms.min.js?ver=1.7.6:formatted`:

```
 formSubmit: function(e) {
        e instanceof jQuery || (e = p(e)),
        l.saveTinyMCE();
        let t = WPFormsUtils.triggerEvent(e, "wpformsBeforeFormSubmit", [e]);
        t.isDefaultPrevented() ? l.restoreSubmitButton(e, e.closest(".wpforms-container")) : e.hasClass("wpforms-ajax-form") && "undefined" != typeof FormData ? l.formSubmitAjax(e) : l.formSubmitNormal(e)
    },
```

I am not a js expert but I think the above code is responsible for form submitting in any case.

Comment: Does `return false` work stead of event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @Ajay No it does not work either.

Comment: Do you really have more than one element with the same id? Unclear why you would use an each when you are selecting an element with an id selector `"input#wpforms-2185-field_0"`

Comment: Does the code get triggered on submit? Does it go into the each. Does it have a length? Does it go into the if?

Comment: @epascarello: Yes the code get triggered on submit, it does have length and it goes to the `if`, but it ignores `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not preventing spam this way, because your form can still be submitted regardless of javascript or html. Also, might consider using `required` attribute on the form fields.

Your code works. Make sure you are having the fields with the correct id's .
and if those are the correct id's then they are not recommended this way because id`s should be unique.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $("#wpforms-form-2185").submit(function(event) {
    $("input#wpforms-2185-field_0").each(function() {
      var words = $.trim($(this).val()).split(" ");
      //alert(words.length);
      if (words.length != 2) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="wpforms-form-2185">
  <input id="wpforms-2185-field_0">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: In the above snippet it is working. Is the script included in the your final html?

Comment: Yes jquery version is 3.6.0.

Comment: Check the console for errors & Debug each step, just don't focus on the final condition, write debugging code, for example. validation if the button click code is working. if it works then `console.log` a message, then move to the next line and next line and find the problem.

Comment: @VijayHardaha: the server belongs to the school network and when there are many form submissions an SMTP error ensuees "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.", so I have to wait some hours to so as the connection is restored. In that case I get an 504 error as well as an "WPForms AJAX submit error". in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a lot of this kind of thing in my own application that uses WPForms extensively. I often find myself needing more nuanced form validation. My first thought on reading your question was to use Input Mask, but I'm not totally sure that would prevent the form submit, it might though, here's some [documentation](https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-use-custom-input-masks/#advanced), and seems like you could use an input mask something like:

```
Aa{1,25} Aa{1,25}
```

If that works, that's probably the easiest solution, however, that's gonna require you to place some intentional limitations on the length of your names and maybe you don't want to do that, and as I said, I don't know exactly how the input masks work with the form validation.

So, an alternative would be to tap into the library that WPForms uses for form validation, [jquery-validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). After your form loads, you can add custom validation rules to any of the fields. Here's some example code:

First, when the page loads, you extend the validation plugin's rules like this:

```js
if($.validator) {
    $.validator.addMethod("two_words", function(value, element, params) {
        return this.optional( element ) || ($.trim(value).split(" ")).length==2;
    }, 'Field must contain two words.');
}
```

Here, I'm just adding a rule with the key 'two_words' that just checks whether the field is optional or meets the criteria you specified.

Then, when the form loads, you can add your rule to a specific field like this:

```js
self.wpFormsField(formId,10).rules("add", {
    required: true,
    two_words: true,                                
    messages: {
        required: "Gotta know who you is sucka!",
        two_words: "Field must contain two words brosephus!"
    }
});
```

First I'm just selecting the WPForms field I want to add my rule to (using my own convenience function, don't worry about that, you can just select the field using it's id, e.g., `$("#wpforms-formId-field_fieldId").rules...`). Then, I'm passing an object that specifies my rule 'two_words' as true. I'm also marking the field as required here, but you can do that from the form creation screen as well. And finally, I'm specifying some custom messages for each of the rules I've added. If you don't specify these here, it will just use the default message for the given validation rule.

And that's it. I tested it out and it seems to do the trick:

[Fails Validation - Field is Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzfCh.png)

[Fails Validation - Only One Word Given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbHbg.png)

[Passes Validation - Two Words Given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1OXx.png)

Note that there are a number of different ways you can add validation rules to fields, including doing so without extending the plugin's rule set, I'm just doing it this way because I'm loading a lot of my forms on demand. Check the plugin [rules documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) for more.

Good luck!